# Excel 2010 find and replace: Replace with found wildcard

Tags: regex, excel

I am trying to truncate some data in an excel sheet by removing the second word (if applicable) from each cell. That is, if a cell has two words, I want it to remove the second one. An example would be finding `foo bar` and replacing it with `foo`. From research, I found that the following works in Excel 2011 (for Mac), but not other versions:

```
Find: (*) (*)
Replace with: \1
```

How can I accomplish this in my version of Excel? Also, is there an alternative method by which I can obtain the same result?

Comment: For anyone having this issue, it can be accomplished by going to Data > "Text to Columns", selecting 'Delimited", and checking "space" (or whatever delimiter is used). This will seperate the data into two columns, the second of which can simply be deleted to accomplish the desired result. I'm still interested in other methods that may be out there however. :)

Comment: Excel 2010 (and earlier) do not support regular expressions (except for limited wild-card use) as in your example above.  In addition to text-to-columns, you could use a VBA macro.  And if you didn't mind some extra steps, you could use a formula.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a formula..

```
=IF(FIND(" ",A2),TRIM(LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2))),A2)
```

or a VBA subroutine..

```
Sub GetFirstWord()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False    

    Dim n As Integer
    Dim strWord As String

    n = 2

    Do While Cells(n, 1).Value <> ""

        strWord = Cells(n, 1).Value

        If InStr(1, strWord, " ") Then

           Cells(n, 1).Value = Replace(Left(strWord, InStr(1, strWord, " ")), strWord, "")

        End If

        n = n + 1

    Loop


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub
```

Both solutions as written above assume the words are located in Column A.